# Matplotlib: panel label out of the box, above the ylabel

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been using matplotlib for all my publication-use figures, and one question is: how to I place the panel labels that is out of the box? The tutorial is shown [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html#axes-coordinates), with the code and result:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
for i, label in enumerate(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,i+1)
    ax.text(0.05, 0.95, label, transform=ax.transAxes,
      fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')

plt.show()
```

[image: Panel labeling]

But the panel label is only at the corner of the bounding box, not out side of the box and above the y axis label (which is the usual way), like this:

[image: Plos One format]

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is best to paste the code you are using directly into the question rather than linking to external sites.

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell! I have copied the code in.

Comment: Thanks.  The reason is that links will rot and websites change over time.  If this question is going to be useful to someone a few years down the line, they need to be able to see the code.

Comment: @tcaswell Yea, that totally makes sense. Thanks for explaining! :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

values outside of `[0, 1]` are valid.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
for i, label in enumerate(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,i+1)
    ax.text(-0.1, 1.15, label, transform=ax.transAxes,
      fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top', ha='right')

plt.show()
```

[image]